# Insertar una cantidad de registros consecutivos en MySql y asignar un nombre al registro

Tags: php, mysql

Explico el titulo.
Estoy usando PHP y mi base de datos es en MySQL, en la pagina le pregunto usuario estos valores:

```
$idlotefin = '';
$cajainicial = '';
$cajafinal = '';
$cantidadcajas = $cajafinal - $cajainicial + 1;
```

Los valores de caja siempre deben ser menor y mayor respectivamente.

La estructura de mi tabla solamente tiene:

```
CREATE TABLE `tt_cajaslotefin` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idlotefin` int DEFAULT NULL,
`nombrecaja` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`fechacreacion` date DEFAULT (curdate()),
`horacreacion` time DEFAULT (curtime()),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Entonces, yo debo tomar el numero que esta en $cantidadcajas e insertar esa cantidad de registros en la tabla tt_cajaslotefin, pero entonces cada registro en nombrecaja debe llevar el consecutivo de caja que le corresponde, por ejemplo.

```
    $idlotefin = 15;
    $cajainicial = 500;
    $cajafinal = 505;
    $cantidadcajas = $cajafinal - $cajainicial + 1;
    $cantidadcajas = 6
```

Al ejecutar el insert, debería quedar de esta forma:

```
    id |idlotefin|nombrecaja|fechacreacion|horacreacion|
    ---+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
     97|       15|500       |   2023-07-14|    14:38:26|
     98|       15|501       |   2023-07-14|    14:38:26|
     99|       15|502       |   2023-07-14|    14:38:26|
    100|       15|503       |   2023-07-14|    14:38:26|
    101|       15|504       |   2023-07-14|    14:38:26|
    102|       15|505       |   2023-07-14|    14:38:26|
```

Hasta el momento, he logrado insertar la cantidad de registros de $cantidadcajas, pero no encuentro la forma de darle el nombre correcto a la caja con el consecutivo.

Dejo el fragmento del codigo que debe ejecutar esto:

```
    $idlotefin = 10;
    $cajainicial = 12;
    $cajafinal = 20;
    $cantidadcajas = $cajafinal - $cajainicial + 1;
    
    try {
        // Insertar los registros en la tabla tt_cajaslotefin
        $queryInsertCajas = "INSERT INTO tt_cajaslotefin (idlotefin, nombrecaja) VALUES ";
        $nombrecaja = $cajainicial + 1;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $cantidadcajas; $i++) {
            $queryInsertCajas .= "(:idlotefin, :nombrecaja$i), ";
            $nombrecaja++;
        }
        $queryInsertCajas = rtrim($queryInsertCajas, ", "); // Eliminar la última coma y espacio
    
        $stmtInsertCajas = $pdo->prepare($queryInsertCajas);
        $stmtInsertCajas->bindParam(':idlotefin', $idlotefin, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $cantidadcajas; $i++) {
            $stmtInsertCajas->bindParam(":nombrecaja$i", $nombrecaja, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $nombrecaja++;
        }
        $stmtInsertCajas->execute();
```

Agradezco mucho la ayuda. Si es necesario, puedo modificar lo que sea, la forma de procesarlos, triggers, procedure o si sea el PHP o MySQL que deba realizar la acción.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, dinos qué obtienes, qué te gustaría obtener y el error que recibes. Quizá lo único que te falte sea un `$stmtInsertCajas->close();` al final. También puedes omitir la consulta preparada, como lo único que insertas son valores enteros, usa `intval()` que por ahí no te van a poder inyectar código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifícalo un poco, tal que así:

```
<?php

$idlotefin = 10;
$cajainicial = 12;
$cajafinal = 20;

// Insertar los registros en la tabla tt_cajaslotefin
$queryInsertCajas = "
    INSERT INTO tt_cajaslotefin
      (idlotefin, nombrecaja)
      VALUES 
";
for ($i = $cajainicial; $i <= $cajafinal; $i++)
    $queryInsertCajas .= "("
        .intval($idlotefin)
        .","
        .intval($i)
        ."),";
$queryInsertCajas = rtrim($queryInsertCajas, ", ").";";
$pdo->query($queryInsertCajas);
```

Verás que he omitido la consulta preparada porque, a través de valores enteros y haciendo uso de `intval()`, no podrán inyectarte código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la he ajustado y por fin obtuve lo que pretendía hacer.